# How to make a row bold from within the adapter class in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I would like to made the rows bold that starts with the word "Main".
This is inside an adapter of a RecycleView, hence some limitations are expected. e.g. I can't obtain the view via FindViewById().

My solution below works, but it feels very wrong, given I'm importing `server_detail_id`.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.row_item_detail.view.server_detail_id


class ServerDetailAdapter(private var serverList: ArrayList<ServerDetailRow>, context: Context?) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<DefaultViewHolder>() {

     override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DefaultViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val serverRow: ServerDetailRow = serverList[position]
            val server = serverRow.server
            val context = holder.itemView.context
            var serverName = server.serverName
            if (serverName.startsWith("Main", false)) {
               holder.itemView.server_detail_id.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
            }
            holder.setText(R.id.server_detail_id, serverName)
     }
}
```

Any suggestions how I could solve this better?

Comment: In `ViewHolder` constructor didn't you inflate `R.id.server_detail_id` with `FindViewById`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#ViewHolder(android.view.View)) for the view holder, you are given the item view. You can do a `findViewById()` on this view, store the result and refer to it in `onBindViewHolder()`.

On a separate topic, you will want to always set the type face in `onBindViewHolder()` since the view holders are reused.

Comment: A code-snippet example could have helped a lot to clarify this. But I got the idea and was able to fix it. Thanks